# WPF content binding - want to display two attributes of a ListView in a StatusBarItem

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have a `StatusBarItem` which I want to display the following message at any given moment "X/Y" where X is the number of the row of the currently selected element, and Y is the row count.

Now, if I use the `Content="{Binding ElementName=lvTabela, Path=SelectedIndex}"` code in xaml I am able to get the first attribute to display, but I'm not sure how I can get both.

I suppose I could always use two `StatusBarItem` elements next to each other, but I'd like to learn how to do this as well.

Oh, and while we're at it, how would I go about incrementing the selected index? Basically, instead of -1 to rowCount-1 I'd like it to display 0 to rowCount. I've seen people using the formatter to add additional text to their data binding, but I'm not sure how I can manipulate the data like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got 2 options:

Either set the `Content` of the `StatusbarItem` a `TextBlock` to use `StringFormat` with `MultiBinding`, Something like:

```
<StatusBarItem>
  <StatusBarItem.Content>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}/{1}">
          <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding ElementName="listView"
                      Path="SelectedIndex" />
            <Binding ElementName="listView"
                      Path="Items.Count" />
          </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
  </StatusBarItem.Content>
</StatusBarItem>
```

or use a Converter on the `MultiBinding` to not have to use the `TextBlock`

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:InfoConverter x:Key="InfoConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<StatusBarItem>
  <StatusBarItem.Content>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource InfoConverter}">
      <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding ElementName="listView"
                  Path="SelectedIndex" />
        <Binding ElementName="listView"
                  Path="Items.Count" />
      </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
  </StatusBarItem.Content>
</StatusBarItem>
```

and InfoConverter.cs:

```
class InfoConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    return values[0].ToString() + "/" + values[1].ToString();
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

`StatusBarItem` expects an object, when `StringFormat` returns a string and hence why we cannot use `StringFormat` with the `MultiBinding` without the `TextBlock` which can take a string in it's `Text` field.

As for your second question on how to increment the `SelectedIndex` value, you can do that with the Converter easily,

Just switch the `Convert(...)` function in `InfoConverter.cs` to

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
  return (System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]) + 1).ToString() + "/" + values[1].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both methods are very good. Is it possible, however, to increment the first value using the first method somehow? It's a lot cleaner, but if it isn't possible I'll have to use the second method.

Comment: Nope no ways around that AFAIK when you need to tweak the binding value with the first method. StringFormat is just a formatter pretty much.